# Link hover css doesn't work

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<a class="topofpage" href="#top">TOP OF PAGE</a>
```

CSS

```
.topofpage{
    color: #C00;    
    text-decoration: none;
}

.topofpage a:hover{
    color: #FCO;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

On mouse over color is not changed to #FCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply a confusion between zeros and the letter 'O'.

Your colour is specified as `#FCO`. It should be `#FC0`.

The letter 'O' is not a valid digit in CSS colours. This is why your style does not work. It has nothing to do with it being hovered or not; it's a simple typo.

Hope that solves it for you.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the anchor element in your CSS on hover event.

```
.topofpage:hover{
    color: #FC0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I removed the a and left `.topofpage:hover` - the same result. Color is not changed.

Comment: @Alegro You still got O (latin capital letter O) instead of 0 (digit zero) in your color value.

Comment: @Pavlo, you're right. I copied the wrong code from another place. Thanks for sharp eye.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS targets a link that is inside an element with the class `topofpage`. Put the selectors together to target a link that has the class:

```
a.topofpage:hover {
  color: #FC0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Also, as Pavlo spotted, you are using `#FCO` instead of `#FC0` for the color.

Comment: Right, but the `a` is only necessary for specificity reasons.

Comment: @feeela: Yes, for only the code shown the `a` is not needed. I wanted to keep it as there might be a reason that the OP put it there in the first place.